# How to create an Excel Document when adding a Library Item?

Tags: document-library, event-receivers, excel

Hope you can help me with this question:

I have a SP Library, where the user should type info into some fields (Text, Publishing HTML, Datetime). So, I'm wondering if it's possible to use that info to fill an Excel Template and save it to the Library item the user is adding?

Is this possible with Event receivers, or how would I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can accomplish this with an event receiver on ItemAdded (and potentially ItemUpdated).  You can easily generate a standard XML or CSV file which can then be opened in Excel, or use the Open XML SDK to create native excel files (http://openxmldeveloper.org/).

If you wanted to have this work on 'ItemUpdated', you could lookup the existing excel document and regenerate it based on the latest listitem properties.

Some more info [is here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2010-Creating-a11f6e68).

Comment: If I got Sharepoint 2013 , could I create the event receiver for that library in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: I haven't tried that exact combo myself, but according to this question it should work:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918826/using-visual-studio-2010-with-sharepoint-2013